# Poisson compounding distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

The number of coins that Mr.X spots when walking to work is poisson random variable with mean 6. Each coin is equally likely to be a penny, a nickel,a dime, or a quarter.Mr.X ignores the pennies but picks up the other coins.

(a) I want to Find the expected amount of money that Mr.X on his way to work.

(b)I want to find the variance of the amount of money that Mr.X picks up on his way to work.

(c)I also want to find the probability that Mr.X picks up exactly 25 cents on his way to work.
**SOLUTIONS:**

(a) Let M denote the amount of money Mr.X picks up when he spots a coin.Then

$E(M)=\frac{(5+10+25)}{4}=10$

$E(M^2)=\frac{(25+100+625)}{4}=\frac{750}{4}$

Therefore, the amount he picks up on his way to work is compound poisson random variable with mean 10*6=60

(b)Variance of the amount of money that Mr.X picks up on his way to work is $\frac{6*750}{4}= 1125$

(c) Now how to solve (c)? To solve (c), we can either use recursion  formula or condition on the number of pickups to determine $P(S=25 cents)$

Recursion formula is as follows:

$P_0=e^{-\lambda}$

$P_k=\frac{\lambda}{k}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\alpha_j P_{k-j},  K>0$

Would any one answer by both methods?

Comment: In (a) and (b), what justifies ignoring the fact that the number of coins is random?  This is especially relevant to computing the variance.

Comment: @whuber, Expectation of compound poisson random variable is $\lambda E(M)$ and its variance is $\lambda E(M^2)$

Comment: These follow from the law of total expectation and law of total variance.